# Files' 'color tags' no longer persistent?

Tags: release-juno, files

Color tags in elementary are consistently failing after reboot or restart 'Files' application. This behavior only recently started happening.  I am running a 'vanilla' Juno release.  I keep elementary up to date (see below for configuration information).  Is this a known problem?  If so, is there a fix in work?

Operating System: elementary OS 5.0 Juno
Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-65-generic
Architecture: x86-64